# Displaying array elements in a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

****I am very new to Java and android studio and am trying to  display an individual element of my array into my textView *wordTextView* with every click of a button. When I click the button on the emulator nothing is being displayed. I have also tried to use a for loop yet I cannot seem to get that to work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated****

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void nextWord(View view) { //nextWord is the onclick of the button
        i = i++;
    }

    public void getNextWord(String string) {
        String [] array = {"Noun", "Adjective", "Proper Noun", "Name"};
        TextView wordTextView = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);
        wordTextView.setText(array[i]);    
    }
}
```

Here is the .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="nextWord"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wordTextView"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Something"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/wordTextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:onClick="nextWord"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/enterEditText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int i = 0;

    TextView wordTextView; // declare your textView here

    // no need to create array again in "getNextWord" method
    String[] array = {"Noun", "Adjective", "Proper Noun", "Name"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        // initialise text view here
        wordTextView = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);
    }

    public void nextWord(View view) { //nextWord is the onclick of the button
        i = i++;
        getNextWord() // call this method here, without passing string
    }

    public void getNextWord() {
        // you need to check the value of "i", it should not be greater than "array" size.
        // you can simply do 
        // i = i% array.length
        // or you can check index with if-condition
        // otherwise you will get "ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" if i >= array.length
        wordTextView.setText(array[i]);    
    }
}
```

Comment: @RyanMurphy if it works, don't forget to accept or upvote answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Call your getNextWord() method in nextWord()

```
public void nextWord(View view) { //nextWord is the onclick of the button
    i = i++;
getNextWord();
}
```

> And remove parameter from getNextWord().

Comment: It's my pleasure. You can upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: I would do but I my reputation is less that 15. Sorry about that